# Aggregation of calculated column in pivot table is not showing correct

Tags: python, pandas

I have  created a calculated column('%') in my dataframe based on two other column values('Earned_Hours' / 'Total_Hours'). When I pivot_table the calculated column, the aggregation does not seem to be correct.

When dividing the columns I have tried using astype float. I have also tried to use the aggregation sum setting in the pivot table. I also replace any NAN values.

```
df["%"] = (df.Earned_Hours / df.Total_Hours)

df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

pd.pivot_table(df,values =['%'],index=df['Year_Month'],columns='Manager',fill_value = 0)
```

The end result is incorrect when I pivot the info. As an example I expect 20 403.125 / 55 751 = 0.36, however in the pivot table it is 0.439254.

Any assitance is appreciated.

[[image: Calculated Column[1]]
[[image: Total_Hours[2]]
[image: Earned_Hours]

```
Total_Hours Year_Month Earned_Hours  %
        50.0    2019-01 18.0    0.360000
        140.0   2019-01 99.0    0.707143
        90.0    2019-01 72.0    0.800000
        140.0   2019-01 99.0    0.707143
        54.0    2019-01 45.0    0.833333
        150.0   2019-01 126.0   0.840000
        150.0   2019-01 126.0   0.840000
        60.0    2019-01 25.2    0.420000
        80.0    2019-01 120.0   1.500000
        40.0    2019-01 60.0    1.500000
        160.0   2019-01 225.0   1.406250
        50.0    2019-01 0.0     0.000000
        100.0   2019-01 0.0     0.000000
        20.0    2019-01 0.0     0.000000
        20.0    2019-01 0.0     0.000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is default aggregate function in [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) is `mean`, so data are aggregated, because there are duplicated `Manager` with `Year_Month` values.

> **aggfunc** : function, list of functions, dict, default numpy.mean
>
> If list of functions passed, the resulting pivot table will have hierarchical columns whose top level are the function names (inferred from the function objects themselves) If dict is passed, the key is column to aggregate and value is function or list of functions

**Solution**:

```
print (df)
   Total_Hours Year_Month  Earned_Hours Manager
0         50.0    2019-01          18.0      m1
1        140.0    2019-01          99.0      m1
2         90.0    2019-02          72.0      m1
3        140.0    2019-02          99.0      m1
4         54.0    2019-02          45.0      m1
5        150.0    2019-01         126.0      m2
6        150.0    2019-01         126.0      m2
7         60.0    2019-01          25.2      m3
8         80.0    2019-01         120.0      m3
```

I suggest first aggregate `sum` af both columns, then divide for percentage and last reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['Year_Month','Manager']).sum()
df["%"] = (df.Earned_Hours / df.Total_Hours)

print (df)
                    Total_Hours  Earned_Hours         %
Year_Month Manager                                     
2019-01    m1             190.0         117.0  0.615789
           m2             300.0         252.0  0.840000
           m3             140.0         145.2  1.037143
2019-02    m1             284.0         216.0  0.760563

df = df['%'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
Manager           m1    m2        m3
Year_Month                          
2019-01     0.615789  0.84  1.037143
2019-02     0.760563  0.00  0.000000
```

Comment: Thaks jezrael when I tried the aggfunc = 'sum, it also didn't work. When i look at the ['%']  filtered for a specific manager the rows do show correct result but i am not sure why I cant aggregate correctly.

Comment: @Reiss - sorry, can you add some sample data and expcted output? Because hard debud data if see only 3 output rows.

Comment: @Reiss - here is problem cannot [copy data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), can you create text version or change `df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Manager':list('aabbcc'),
         'Year_Month':['2019-01','2019-02','2019-01','2019-01','2019-01','2019-01'],
         '%':[7,8,9,4,2,3],

})` ?

Comment: ok I included the  sample data now, not sure if that will help.

Comment: @Reiss - thank you, what is expected correct output after pivot_table ?

Comment: @Reiss - thank you for data, my answer was edited. Please check it.